# Building Zimbra

Tags: build, zimbra

I want to know why in the Zimbra Wiki only specific platforms are listed for build process. This means that building Zimbra on other for example Linux distributions is impossible?
What is the real reason behind the choice of a special Linux distribution for building Zimbra by the Zimbra community?

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently trying to set up Zimbra on Arch Linux and I'm getting behind those reasons.

Imho Zimbra is a nice piece of work on the outside, useful webmail client, integrates various stuff nicely, etc. BUT the whole package violates every assumption you ever had about server software on linux by bundling and compiling nearly all libraries and third party software into it, this goes as far as basic stuff like popt.
The stated requirement is that you set up Zimbra on a machine on its own and don't you dare to run something else on there.

Since everything is so tightly integrated it's a huge thing to compile and since each bundled software may need to be compiled differently on any distro or anything might break anywhere, the effort must be huge to maintain a sane build for more than a handful of platforms.

It also boggles my mind how anyone could ever think this bundling a good idea. If any security issues arise in a single piece of it, everything must be rebuilt. Instead of the admin relying on the security updates of their distro, they must patch Zimbra themselves, etc.

It seems that building Zimbra on any platform is quite the adventure, to put it mildly. The only platform documented nicely and up to date is FreeBSD which is largely due to a single person not associated with Zimbra, as far as I can see.

Comment: Actually i built it successfully on Mint, Fedora 14 and Debian Squeez_amd64. Non of them are supported platforms. Installation also goes fine but running it is a real mess. So as i understood building it is possible but maintenance during a long period on an undocumented platform is a real challenge!!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah, but Mint, Fedora 14 and Debian Squeeze are still very much like the supported systems (Ubuntu, Fedora 13, Debian 5). After spending far too much effort on making those bundled ThirdParty versions compile on Arch (meaning GCC 4.7, etc.), I'm now trying to wrap my head around what goes wrong during the actual build of the Zimbra core and its packaging. I don't think I will go ahead actually - rather I'll do a chroot with a supported distro and just stop caring about this ugly mess.

Answer (score 2):

I was the build engineer of a Zimbra based project for about a year. We were building it using CentOS. Building Zimbra almost on every platform is possible. It's just a matter of experience and proficiency, since too many programming languages and related technologies are involved in build process and you need to install the exact required version. Thus you might be forced to compile and build some extra packages as well.

I remember that first time that I tried to build Zimbra, It took about 2 weeks for a successful build. However I documented the process completely and clearly. Later on, it took about a night to build Zimbra.